# Swift 5.7: is `guard let self` enough now?

Tags: swift, weak

I used to write stuff like this before Swift 5.7:

```
// random async completion block    
{ [weak self] in
    guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
    weakSelf.someString = ""
}
```

Now I would prefer writing this:

```
// random async completion block    
{ [weak self] in
    guard let self else { return }
    self.someString = ""
}
```

But can I do this without any issue, like retain cycles?

Thank you

Comment: Why not simply `self?.someString = ""` without the `guard` line? If it's `nil` it returns silently.

Comment: It is not the question though. Let's assume it is a piece of code where `guard let self` is justified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's, because the `guard let self` else & `guard let weakSelf = self` is the same thing

To avoid the retain cycle you are using weak, that's other thing

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain with other objects as well these days. If I do something like: guard let foo else { return } it's all good.
But I thought this new feature was only for 'self'?